# Let X, Y be independent random variables and each one has E(1)(exponential distribution). Prove that $W_1, W_2$ are independent.

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

$W_1=\min \{X,Y\}$;$\ \ W_2=X-Y$

It's given that the density functions for $(X,Y),W_1$ and $W_2$ respectively are: $$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=e^{-(x+y)};f_{W_1}(u)=2e^{-2u}, u>0,f_{W_2}(v)={e^{|v|}\over 2}$$

The following picture is then given:
[image]

Goes on to find:
$$F_{(W_1,W_2)}(u,v)=P\{W_1<u,W_2<v\}=\int_{0}^{u}e^{-x}dx\int_{x-v}^{\infty}e^{-y}dy={(1-e^{-2u}e^v)\over 2}, v<0.$$
$$F_{(W_1,W_2)}(u,v)=\int_{0}^{u}e^{-y}dy\int_{y}^{y+v}e^{-x}dx+\int_{0}^{u}e^{-x}dx\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-y}dy,  v>0.$$

Then it finds the densities of each, which I understand, could someone explain the reasoning behind these areas? How are these the areas of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to this routine computation, the result follows from the Lack of Memory property of the exponential distribution.  Moreover, this 
doesn't depend on the exponentials having the same parameter.
Think of $X$ and $Y$ as waiting times for events A and B respectively.
The first of the two events occurs at time $\min(X,Y)$, and its probability of
being A does not depend on that time.
Once the first event occurs, the remaining time until the second occurs still has the same distribution as the original waiting time, and this remaining time is either $X-Y$ (if B occurred first) or $Y-X$ (if A occurred first).  So the conditional distribution of $X-Y$ given $\min(X,Y)=z$ does not depend on $z$, which says $X-Y$ and $\min(X,Y)$ are independent.